# Native Facebooklogin to Xamarin WebApp

Tags: android, ios, facebook, xamarin, web-applications

I have a webapp where you can Login using Facebook and Google. I now packaged the Webapp within a native Xamarin App (not Forms - should I use Forms?).
How Can I create a Native Facebooklogin (using the facebook app) instead of launching facebook inside the webview?

Comment: how did you package it? using a webview and loading the remote website?

Comment: Not sure but probably you will have to use Xamarin Facebook SDKs

Comment: Yes, in iOS I use the WKWebView, but I think I will migrate to Forms

Comment: Not sure it is possible. It could be possible if you managed to listen to a javascript event (button click e.g.) from C# and handle it from there to login with Xamarin Facebook SDK and pass the results back to your website

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I create a Native Facebooklogin (using the facebook app) instead of launching facebook inside the webview?

You can follow the below steps to add facebook login function to your app:

1. Search [`Xamarin.Facebook.Android`](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid) in `NugetPackageManager` and add it to your Xamarin.Android App.
2. Add `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` to your manifest:

   ```
   <application android:label="YourProjectName">
   <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
         android:configChanges=
           "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
         android:label="@string/ApplicationName" />
   </application>
   ```
3. Add `facebook_app_id` to `String.xml`:

   ```
   <resources>
        ...
       <string name="ApplicationName">YourProjectName</string>
       <string name="facebook_app_id">1429006317193169</string>
   </resources>
   ```
4. In your MainActivity.cs add `MetaData` and `Permission` attributes like below:

   ```
   [assembly:MetaData("com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId",Value = "@string/facebook_app_id")]
   [assembly:Permission(Name = Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
   [assembly:Permission(Name = Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
   namespace YourProjectName
   {
      ...
   }
   ```
5. Add a `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` to your `xaml`:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
       android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
6. Register the login callbacks in your Activity:

   ```
   public class MainActivity : Activity
   {
       ICallbackManager callbackManager;
       LoginButton btnLogin;
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           base.OnCreate(bundle);

           SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
           callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
           btnLogin = FindViewById<LoginButton>(Resource.Id.btnLogin);

           LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, new MyCallbackResult());
       }



       protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
       {
           int code = 0;
           if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
           {
               code = -1;
           }
           else if (resultCode == Result.FirstUser)
           {
               code = 1;
           }
           callbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, code, data);
       }
   }

   public class MyCallbackResult : Java.Lang.Object, IFacebookCallback
   {
       public void OnCancel()
       {
           //login cancel callback
       }

       public void OnError(FacebookException p0)
       {
           //login error callback
       }

       public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object p0)
       {
          //Login success callback
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am using Xamarin Forms, so I will have to try to implement your solution with Native Pages. I hope that it works how it should work.